# Self association with accepted nested attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

```
class Employee < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :subordinates, class_name: "Employee", foreign_key: "manager_id"
  belongs_to :manager, class_name: "Employee", optional: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :subordinates
end
```

How to create employee_params in controller for deep nested association like above.

```
def employee_params
  params.require(:employee).permit(:name, :roll_no, subordinates_attributes: [:name, roll_no, :subordate_attributes:[]......])
end
```

Comment: To clarify, from the UX perspective... the end user creates multiple employees and assigns them to each other before submitting and committing the whole thing to the server? I can't help but feel this makes the UI overly complex ... how would you handle validation errors... etc

Comment: I am not using this for creating employee. Its for a different purpose.

Comment: Ok the same question stands ... just replace `employee` in my comment with whatever it is you are attempting to create. Just trying to help clarify the purpose, because it seems it would be simpler in this case to remove the accepts_nested_attributes_for and just `permit(:name, :roll_no, :manager_id, subordinate_ids: [])`.

Answer (score 0):

Just pass a hash as the last element of the array to permit an array of nested attributes:

```
def employee_params
  params.require(:employee).permit(
     :name, :roll_no, 
     subordinates_attributes: [
       :name, :roll_no, 
       subordinates_attributes: [:name, :roll_no]
     ]
  )
end
```

This syntax looks really strange but works since `[1, 2, 3, foo: :bar] == [1, 2, 3, {:foo=>:bar}]`.

Comment: @David is spot on in his comments though. Megaforms make for huge messes and a poor UX. And if you are just selecting existing records you don't need nested attributes.